# TypeError HTTP Call Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Currently, I'm building a backend system which gets information from several devices in my network. On some devices I use the "PUT" method to change values.

```
Meteor.http.put('http://192.168.178.98:8080/test' , {content: "1"}, {headers:{"content-type":"text/plain"}});
```

That's working but after two minutes my server is crashing with this error:

> W20160212-09:50:46.430(1)? (STDERR) TypeError: object is not a function
>   W20160212-09:50:46.430(1)? (STDERR) at packages/http/httpcall_server.js:74:1 W20160212-09:50:46.430(1)? (STDERR) at packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1 W20160212-09:50:46.431(1)? (STDERR)     at Request._callback (packages/http/httpcall_server.js:116:1)
>   W20160212-09:50:46.431(1)? (STDERR) at Request.self.callback (/home/pd/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.1.158nqs7++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:344:22) W20160212-09:50:46.431(1)? (STDERR) at Request.emit (events.js:98:17) W20160212-09:50:46.431(1)? (STDERR) at Request.  home/pd/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.1.158nqs7++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1239:14) W20160212-09:50:46.431(1)? (STDERR) at Request.emit (events.js:117:20) W20160212-09:50:46.431(1)? (STDERR) at IncomingMessage. /home/pd/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.1.158nqs7++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1187:12) W20160212-09:50:46.431(1)? (STDERR) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20) W20160212-09:50:46.432(1)? (STDERR) at _stream_readable.js:944:16 => Exited with code: 8 => Meteor server restarted

It's a server side method called by the clients.

How can I fix this? Is it possible to disable callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put headers in the params object!
Read the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_put).

```
Meteor.http.put('http://192.168.178.98:8080/test', {
    content: "1",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "text/plain"
    }
}, function(err, res) {

});
```